# Are there any disadvantages or side-effects to writing all async code in IIFEs?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I've become enamored with the async/await syntax for consuming promises since it looks and acts like synchronous code.

Although I see most examples of async/await with named functions, I find that I always write async/await code now in IIFEs, since it is mere syntactic sugar anyway, like this:

```
btnInOrderElem.onclick = () => {
    (async () => {
        contentElem.innerHTML = '';
        loaderAreaElem.style.display = 'inline';
        addLi(await loader.getData());
        addLi(await loader.getData());
        addLi(await loader.getData());
        loaderAreaElem.style.display = 'none';
    })();
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing with this practice? Are there disadvantages to doing this at some point? Is there any reason to create named functions in order to run async/await code?

Comment: Only problem I see is you not using addEventListener. ;) It is personal opinion on the best practice.

Comment: Why don't you just pass an async callback? (and use addEventListener ;)) I'm betting you don't call synchronous functions as wrapped IIFEs `const log = () => {(()=>console.log('IIFE?'))();}`

Comment: @epascarello I use addEventListener if I need to, e.g. if I have to pass `{ once: true }`, but if not, I find the `onclick` syntax more succinct and easier to read.

Comment: Is there a reason you use IIFE instead of `btnInOrderElem.onclick = async () => { ... }`?

Comment: @A_A, well, there is a difference, yes. Putting async in the event listener will get the data when you set the listener instead of when the user clicks on the button. It depends on when the data needs to be loaded in each case.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. With `btnInOrderElem.onclick = async () => { ... }` the code inside the brackets (`...`) is only executed every time a user clicks the button. This should be the same as with your example, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @A_A, ok, you seem to be right. I thought I had tested it and it had begun loading when the event was set. Apparently that was some other bug. Ok, thanks. Helpful. Yes, if this is the case, then identifying event listeners as async works nicely.

Comment: The problem with onclick like that is you can only have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, there's really no difference between any of these:

```js
btnInOrderElem.onclick = async () => { ... }

btnInOrderElem.onclick = () => {
  (async () => { ... })()
}

async function onClickHandler() { ... }
btnInOrderElem.onclick = onClickHandler
```

When you define a function as async, it means Javascript will automatically cause that function to always return a promise, that resolves when it's inner tasks are completed. While the function definitions are different in the above code snippets (some would return a promise while others return undefined), the actual program will behave the same, because the browser ignores whatever is returned from the event handler (usually).

If, however, you were writing a utility function like this:

```js
function getUser() {
  (async () => { ... })()
}
// or
async function getUser() { ... }
```

There *is* an important difference. The second function will return a promise, so you can await that promise and get the resulting value. The first function will dispatch an async action then return undefined. You can't get a resulting value out of the first, nor can you await it.

---

Here's an exercise for you.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function waitThenLog(ms, message) {
  await wait(ms)
  console.log(message)
}

;(async function main() {
  await waitThenLog(500, 'Hello World!')
  console.log('done')
})()
```

Above I have a simple program. It'll wait 500ms then log a message, then logs "done". Try changing it so that the waitThenLog() function uses your IIFE idea and see if you can get it to work. You'll find that you will run into some fundamental problems.